# Remove Files & Filegroups from SQL Question

Tags: sql-server

I was tasked to remove a bunch of Files and Filegroups from a SQL database. Now I have read multiple sites but they all use `DBCC SHRINKFILE (N'filename', EMPTYFILE)`.

From the MS document on [SHRINKFILE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-shrinkfile-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) it states"

> EMPTYFILE
> Migrates all data from the specified file to other files in the same filegroup.

I do not want to migrate the data, I want to purge it. Is there any way to purge the data so I can remove the files/filegroups without needing to use SHRINKFILE?

I also do not want to take the database offline if that can be prevented. These files and groups are created by one of our systems, so would prefer that the database remain online so the system can use the database.

It creates a new Group on a monthly basis, and a File for each day. The data we want to remove is from 2019, and no longer needed and we need to recover the space.

TIA

Comment: `EMPTYFILE` is a specific argument meant precisely to help with _removing_ files, and I suspect that's what "multiple sites" were trying to help you with. There are other arguments to `DBCC SHRINKFILE` that don't migrate data away, e.g. `DBCC SHRINKFILE(N'filename', 10);` however if your goal is to _remove_ files and you have data in those files that you don't want to migrate, the data needs to go _somewhere_ - either you need to delete it first or you need to delete it after it has been moved. I'll give you three guesses which is more efficient and log-friendly. :-)

Comment: This is a database, there is no purging of data. If you need data to disappear, you need an explicit `DELETE`, `TRUNCATE` or `DROP TABLE` (depending on what data there is). If the filegroup in question no longer contains data, then you can use `ALTER DATABASE .. REMOVE FILE` and `REMOVE FILEGROUP` to actually remove the files/filegroups in question. `EMPTYFILE` is helpful because often, even if data has been explicitly removed in some other way, files can contain residual metadata that only `EMPTYFILE` can migrate, but that should take little to no time after the data is gone.

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing was setting the database to `RESTRICTED_USER` for a couple of minutes, set all the filegroups to `READWRITE`, then set the database back to `MULTI_USER`. Thus keeping the downtime to a minimum.

After that I ran the `DROP TABLE`, `DBCC SHRINKFILE (..., EMPTYFILE)` and `REMOVE FILE` commands and it cleared up the space on the drive.

Thank you for those that commented, it helped in getting the script working. :)